# Calculate min of rows ignoring NaN values

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have this array and calculate mean of rows:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,np.NaN,4]])

mins = np.min(a, axis = 1)
```

The problem is the output is: `[1.  nan]`.
How to ignore nan in a and get result `[1  2]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use masked arrays

```
mins = list(np.min(np.ma.masked_array(a, np.isnan(a)), axis=1))
```

Answer (score 41):

Another more concise and slightly faster alternative is to use the [`numpy.nanmin()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html) function, which does exactly what you asked for.